# Is there any way to display each variation price changes using variation swatches plugin in woocommerce?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

By using the variation swatches plugin created the variations and then I added this code that displays the price in the header.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'selected_variation_price_replace_variable_price_range');
function selected_variation_price_replace_variable_price_range(){
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type('variable') ):
    ?><style> .woocommerce-variation-price {display:none;} </style>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        var p = 'p.price'
            q = $(p).html();

        $('form.cart').on('show_variation', function( event, data ) {
            if ( data.price_html ) {
                $(p).html(data.price_html);
            }
        }).on('hide_variation', function( event ) {
            $(p).html(q);
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

visit this link please: https://onlinesanitarystore.com/product/iphone-12-pro-max/
Now I want that if the single variation is selected the price should change with it in the header.